# Attempt to assign property

Tags: php, laravel, update

Amigos, me podrían orientar con este problema que tengo, estoy recibiendo un array, pero cuando quiero actualizar los datos a mi base me arroja el siguiente error:

> Attempt to assign property 'stock' of non-object

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
if($det=$request->detalles) {
    foreach ($det as $detalle=> $valor) {
        $detalle=Detalle::where('art_id', '=', $idArt)
            ->where('codigo_id', '=', $valor)
            ->exists();
    }
}

if($detalle==""){
    $doNeg=false;
    $errmesg="No existe articulo";
}

$detalle->stock=1;
$detalle->updated_at = Carbon::now();
if (Auth::guard('supervisor')->check()) {
    $detalle->admin_id= Auth::id();
} elseif (Auth::guard('bodeguero')->check()) {
    $detalle->admin_id= Auth::id();
}
$detalle->save();
```

Mi problema es cuando apretó el botón guardar y me dice que `Attempt to assign property of non-object`, ayuda porfis, porque no se en donde me caigo para poder actualizar mis datos

Comment: El error parece indicar que tienes un typo en algun lugar.  No sera `stock` en lugar de `sotck`?

Comment: Si es stock, he modificado el texto, pero sigo sin encontrar cual es le error que hace que se me caiga y no guarde

Comment: si imprimes el array en el controlador que te muestra?

Comment: En el `foreach` pareces hacer una cosa algo rara: el índice se llama `$detalle` y se asigna una variable llamada `$detalle` a partir del valor. ¿No estará eso creando problemas? ¿Dónde se define la variable `$detalle`? ¿Cuál es su ámbito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando estás llamando a `$detalle->stock`, **$detalle no existe** (a menos que estés omitiendo alguna parte del código).

En tu ciclo:

```
if($det=$request->detalles) {
    foreach ($det as $detalle=> $valor) {
        $detalle=Detalle::where('art_id', '=', $idArt)
            ->where('codigo_id', '=', $valor)
            ->exists();
    }
}
```

Lo único que haces es verificar si existe un Detalle que cumpla con las condiciones solicitadas y guardarlo en $detalle como true o false, porque **exists()** te devuelve **verdadero o falso**.

Si lo que quieres es **instanciar tu $detalle con un tipo Detalle**, tendrías que hacer:

```
$detalle=Detalle::where('art_id', '=', $idArt)
                ->where('codigo_id', '=', $valor)
                ->first();
```

Esto te devolverá una **instancia de Detalle** o **NULL** si no es encontrado.

Pero aún así, como lo haces dentro de un foreach, igualmente **perderás el valor de $detalle al momento de terminar el ciclo**.
Tendrías que llamar a alguna función dentro del mismo ciclo después de instanciar $detalle.
Por ejemplo:

```
if($det=$request->detalles) {
    foreach ($det as $detalle=> $valor) {
        $detalle=Detalle::where('art_id', '=', $idArt)
            ->where('codigo_id', '=', $valor)
            ->first();
        if($detalle) {
            self::hacerLoQueTienesQueHacer($detalle);
        }
    }
}
public static function hacerLoQueTienesQueHacer($detalle)
{
    $detalle->stock=1;
    $detalle->updated_at = Carbon::now();
    if (Auth::guard('supervisor')->check()) {
        $detalle->admin_id= Auth::id();
    } elseif (Auth::guard('bodeguero')->check()) {
        $detalle->admin_id= Auth::id();
    }
    $detalle->save();
}
```

Creé una función estática porque no tengo idea de dónde estás parado en tu código, pero si lo que quieres hacer es una tarea común de Detalle, lo ideal sería que la clase Detalle tuviera una función llamada hacerLoQueTienesQueHacer y en el ciclo simplemente harías:

```
if($det=$request->detalles) {
    foreach ($det as $detalle=> $valor) {
        $detalle=Detalle::where('art_id', '=', $idArt)
            ->where('codigo_id', '=', $valor)
            ->first();
        if($detalle) {
            $detalle->hacerLoQueTienesQueHacer();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Julio muchas gracias, mi error precisamente estaba en utilizar ->exists();, al modificarlo por un first(), me realizó los cambios que quería realizar.  Es algo que jamás se me volverá a olvidar.  Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Genial, me alegro de haberte podido ayudar, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

he verificado que se debe incluir, en este caso; el

```
$detalle->save();
```

dentro del condicional if else

saludos

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).